# Android-circular area extraction from an image using openCV with java

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to segment a circular area in an image and trying to read the RGB values of pixels in the circular area.Can someone refer me to a tutorial,where this is done in openCV for android using java?

Comment: How would you like the pixels in the circular area represented so you can read them? For example as an array of values (r,g,b,x,y)? It might be easier to return as a bounding square matrix with values outside the circle set to say -1.

Comment: Either way is fine.I just need some help,regarding how this can be done.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest the following:

Assuming you know the centre (x,y) and radius r of the circular area, find the submat of the square that bounds the circle, ie. it will have points tl = (x-r, y-r), br = (x+r, y+r):

```
Rect roi = new Rect(new Point(x-r, y-r,), new Point(x+r, y+r));
Mat boundingSquare = originalImage.submat(roi);
```

You can then run through each of the points in that submat and test whether they are in the circle. So for each point (a,b) in the submat (which remember will now have top left point (0,0) and bottom right (2r,2r)), check whether (a-r)*(a-r)+(b-r)*(b-r) <= r*r.

A slightly different approach (and assuming your point values are positive) is to create a masking Mat of say values 1 in the circle and -1 outside (using the same technique above); you can then multiple the mask with your boundingSquare (or a clone of it to be more accurate) using Core.multiply. boundingSquare will then have positive values inside the circle and negative outside. Applying the mask in this way will be quicker than scanning individual pixel values.